# MATLAB - Concatenating 2 wav audio files

Tags: matlab

I have 2 WAV audio files, which I load into MATLAB as follows:

```
[y1,Fs]=audioread('bat-time_x.wav');
y1_sample_rate = 2000;
[y2,Fs]=audioread('believe_me.wav');
y3 = [y1(1:y1_sample_rate:numel(y1)) y2]
sound(y3,Fs);
```

How can I concatenate these to play one after the other?

Comment: If the sampling rate is equal: `y3 = [y1 y2]` would already do. If the sampling rate is not equal, one (or both) signals need to be resampled to the same frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You want to audioread both files and check their sample rate. If they are the same, you can concatenate the files.

```
[y1,Fs1]=audioread('bat-time_x.wav');
[y2,Fs2]=audioread('believe_me.wav');

if Fs1 ~= Fs2
error('Need to resample');
end

y3 = [y1; y2];
sound(y3,Fs1);
```

To resample y2 to Fs1 use `resample`.

```
y2 = resample(y2,Fs1,Fs2);
```